# PowerPivot MultiRefresh Per day

Tags: 2010, powerpivot

Is there any way to configure the schedule refresh of the PowerPivot file to refresh the file many times per day. even with writing custom code.

Thanks in advance for you support

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge SharePoint doesn't allow refreshes of less than 1 day.  However there is an additional setting for "as soon as possible" available that refreshes data as soon as resources are available (still starts at the appointed time).

Microsoft has a doc regarding power pivot data refresh available here:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/E/1/BE1AABB3-6ED8-4C3C-AF91-448AB733B1AF/PowerPivotDataRefresh.docx

You'll find the info on the ASAP setting on page 7.

**EDIT**

After further investigation, there is no programmatic method (no methods or functions in the documented API / Web Services) or other method to set the data refresh schedule with v1 to less than 1 day.  MS has not announced any intentions of supporting this feature in a future SP.

Comment: It may be possible to create a custom timer job that "resets" your job schedule so it gets picked up by the PP scheduling job as a new job to process. Can you please guide me more. this can be done by SharePoint object Model?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint doesn't allow it, but refactoring the stanadard code you can resolve it. I published a sample code in https://forcepowerpivotrefre.codeplex.com/