# PowerPivot - On demand data refresh

Tags: powerpivot

I have schedule data refresh and least you can do is 1 data refresh per day. Is there a on demand data refresh option. I click on Data > Refresh selected connection from the web view of the xlsx but that did not refresh the data.

My next schedule is tonight (midnight). What are my option? (timer job?)

Comment: I changed the time for Once a Day job to be 15 minutes from the current time and waited for Refresh to happen. Sure enough, Data was updated. But at the data refresh configuration scheduling piece. I would like know if there is a On-Demand way to do this.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18145/powerpivot-multirefresh-per-day